# Table and column html

Tags: html, css, html-helper, tumblr, html-table

I'm using a theme that has a really nice grid-like effect. The normal amount of td's is 5. But for some sections I only need two, and for others I need more. I'd like to be able to have them all the same size, because whats happening is when I put the proper amount that I require, it will sometimes stretch the boxes too big or too small. Here's the CSS, and if you need anything else, just let me know.

```
body {background-color:#cccccc; color:#000000; font:16px Arial, sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
a {text-decoration:underline; color:black;}
a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
#wrappper {background-color:#ffffff; width:600px; margin:60px auto; padding:0 50px 50px;}
#title {background-color:#000000; color:#ffffff; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase; padding:20px 0; margin:0 -50px 20px;}
table {width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;}
table th {font-size:20px; padding:24px 0 8px; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:left;}
table td {vertical-align:center; padding:4px 1px;}
table table {width:300px; height:50px;}
table table td {border:solid 1px #000000; width:50px; height:50px; padding:0;}
table table td img {display:block; border:0; max-width:30px; max-height:30px; width:auto; height:auto; margin:auto;}
#credit {border-top:solid 2px black; margin-top:40px; padding-top:20px; text-align:center; font-size:12px;}
```

And then heres the colspan I believe...

```
<table>
<col width="auto"><col width="150px"><col width="150px">

<tr><th colspan="2">
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zorabelle/sYJKt/

Comment: are you using colspan?

Comment: Yea, heres the beginning of my table code: <table>
<col width="auto"><col width="150px"><col width="150px">

<tr><th colspan="2">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add empty `<td></td>`s where you have less than 5 in a given `<tr>`. Alternatively, if you want to 'join' `<td>`s, use `colspan`.

EDIT: How about using hidden `<td>`s to maintain the layout, like in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/sYJKt/1/):

```
td.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the problem is. Could you put together a [jsFiddle](www.jsfiddle.com) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Ok, but it's working as expected, no? What about it don't you like?

Comment: I want all the boxes to be the same size.